# Separate Day and Time (h)

Tags: date, time, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm reading from a csv where a column contains both time and date.  I'm looking to separarte time (hour) from the  day but have not been able to. This is my code

```
dat = pd.read_csv('30day.csv')
time = dat['Event_Time']
date_time=pd.to_datetime(time)
```

Which produces

```
0    2014-12-23 06:28:54
1    2014-12-23 06:31:55
2    2014-12-23 06:42:09
3    2014-12-23 06:48:21
4    2014-12-23 06:49:35
5    2014-12-23 06:59:47
6    2014-12-23 06:21:46
7    2014-12-23 06:24:23
8    2014-12-23 06:03:09
9    2014-12-23 06:11:24
10   2014-12-23 06:15:15
11   2014-12-23 06:16:50
12   2014-12-23 06:18:35
13   2014-12-23 06:19:05
14   2014-12-23 06:21:18
Name: Event_Time, Length: 227165, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Any suggestion I should try?

Comment: why don't you try splitting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
date = date_time.apply(lambda x: x.date())
print date

0    2014-12-23
1    2014-12-23
2    2014-12-23
3    2014-12-23
4    2014-12-23

hours = date_time.apply(lambda x: x.hour)
print hours

0    6
1    6
2    6
3    6
4    6
```

Answer (score 0):

`datetime` objects can return an hour. Try:

```
date_time=pd.to_datetime('2014-12-23 06:28:54')
date_time.hour
```

returns
    6